# Loading specific element from ajax and removing element from response

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load an ajax page. I just want the content within the mArray div. The problem I'm having is two-fold. The response I'm getting is sort of an array but it comes with baggage. I'm trying to remove this baggage.

Here's what I mean. When I get the resulting array it comes wrapped in the div I specified, so instead of being ['blah'] it looks more like `<div id="mArray">['blah']</div>`. The other problem is in that mArray div is an ul that I'm trying to get rid of. How do I accomplish this?

Here's what I've tried:

```
    $('#ajaxResults').load('/Default.aspx?PageID=15018909&A=WebApp&CCID=21437&Page=1&Items=500 #mArray');

        // tried this
    $('#ajaxResults').remove('ul');

// doesn't work either
$('#ajaxResults').remove('idOfElement');
```

The other this is the returned results need to be added to an array, the results look something like this (after removing the ul and grabbing the mArray content that is):

```
,['Aaron Young<br />1238 Lincoln Blvd.<br />Santa Monica, CA 90401<br />Region: Pacific<br />Chapter: Sierra Madre<br />Membership Type: Management - Administrative - Support/Youth Development Professional<br />Expires on: Tuesday, August 13, 2013','1238 Lincoln Blvd.,Santa Monica, CA, 90401, USA','7/13/13']
,['Abigail F. Garza<br />Post Office Box 1079<br />Edinburg, TX 78540<br />Region: Southwest<br />Chapter: Edinburg<br />Membership Type: Management - Administrative - Support/Youth Development Professional<br />Expires on: Monday, December 16, 2013','Post Office Box 1079,Edinburg, TX, 78540, USA','11/16/13']
```

This should be added to the array I have waiting already:

```
var webApps = [
    ['leave empty']
    ,['Aaron Young<br />1238 Lincoln Blvd....   //// should go here
];
```

Comment: What is the format of your ajax? Is it in json format? you will need to parse it

Comment: no, it's html. I have that string "array" in the html which i'm rying to extract and then add to an existing array (webApps).